# How to migrate models in Django based on PGsql

Tags: django, postgresql, migrate

I'm following all of the tutorials and references I can reach. However, none of them works. The only thing I want to do is super simple. I just want to add one column to my built model. In this situation, I want to add One ForeignKey to Card. I changed the model then I makemigrations then I migrate. But Django always tell me no migrations apply. Why?

I try to delete all the migration files and migrate again. The same thing happens.

Here are some model files.
...

```py
class Card(models.Model):
   add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   cata = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='夹芯板')
   test_cata = models.ForeignKey(Example,on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True)
   price = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='1')
   noise = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='1')
   flame = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='1')
   moisture = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='1')
   compressive = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='1')
   corrosion = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='1')
   shock = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='1')
   thermal = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='1')
   eng_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='1')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='1')
   card = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   door = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   descrip = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default="",blank=True)
   upload = models.FileField()
   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Example(models.Model):
   filename = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   cata = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

#    image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, upload_to=our_upload_to, default='ourwork/default/default.png', verbose_name='图片')    
#    upload = models.FileField()
   def __str__(self):
       return self.filename
```

...

Here is the command I ran in console.

```
python .\manage.py makemigrations ourwork
```

Then I got:

```
Migrations for 'ourwork':
  ourwork\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Card
    - Create model Entry
    - Create model Example
    - Create model Project
    - Create model Work
    - Add field work to entry
    - Add field test_cata to card
```

```
python .\manage.py migrate
```

Then I got:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, ourwork, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I just want to make my change work in models. T_T

Comment: You don't need to pass ./manage.py when using python in front of it. Either `python manage.py migrate` or `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Thank you Higor, I  deleted python and ran it again but I got the same result.

Comment: If your table is already created the migration won't run. Try to change/add a field to see if it works. Otherwise then you have a problem

Comment: You should not have deleted your existing migrations.

Comment: If you had migrations which you had already run and migrated, then deleted them and ran makemigrations again, Django thinks the new ones you've just created are already in the database so will not migrate them.  If this is a development project and you don't mind losing your current database, delete the database and start again.  If it is an established project, get the migrations back.

Comment: Thank you Henry, your answer should be the accepted one. I deleted the database and fix this problem. But there must be some easier way. Could you please give me more details about rolling migrations back?